# Creating separate pages for each account ASP.net WEB API project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, url-routing

I am new to web API and I am not sure whether it is possible in Web API.

I have an application where I need to create a page for each user of my website. Means if there is a user named JOHN, I need to create a page named www.mysite.com/john.

How can I achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean actual web page (View/Html) or API endpoint (Xml/JSON) because your question is confusing the two

Comment: Its web API project. I am creating aspx pages with ajax calling to API controller.